# iDRAC6 JViewer Unusable

Tags: java, dell, dell-poweredge, drac

I'm getting the following error when trying to launch the Virtual Console, but the Virtual Console Preview works fine (it displays a small preview about once a second). I've confirmed that my M610 DRAC has the latest firmware (3.60 build 3), that Java is properly configured to avoid security issues, and I have the latest version of Oracle Java (version 7 update 55). I'm running OS X, but google shows others having this issue with other operating systems. Perhaps it's an OpenJDK vs Oracle Java issue? I have not been able to test on another client system yet

```
Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.ami.iusb.FloppyRedir.GetKeyboardName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.ami.iusb.FloppyRedir.GetKeyboardName(Native Method)
    at com.ami.iusb.FloppyRedir.ReadKeybdType(FloppyRedir.java:459)
    at com.ami.kvm.jviewer.hid.KVMClient.get_keybd_type(KVMClient.java:735)
    at com.ami.kvm.jviewer.hid.KVMClient.startRedirection(KVMClient.java:727)
    at com.ami.kvm.jviewer.gui.JViewerApp.OnVideoStartRedirection(JViewerApp.java:466)
    at com.ami.kvm.jviewer.gui.JViewerApp.OnConnectToServer(JViewerApp.java:449)
    at com.ami.kvm.jviewer.JViewer.main(JViewer.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same (Kubuntu 12.10 32bit/Firefox 32.0/Oracle Java 8 Update 20 - (build 1.8.0_20-b26)) I was following an alternate advisory regarding a permission manifest attribute, so deleted my Java cache contents. On re-running; I got the above exception.

Comment: For what it's worth, I never did get it running with Java. I used https://github.com/xdissent/ievms and VirtualBox to run a windows environment where I could use the ActiveX iDRAC viewer. Sorry :-(

Comment: @BarnenduGoswami - for what it's worth, these ubuntu console vides codes may end up being valuable to you when you do get DRAC running : http://imgur.com/fNruuUO

Answer (score 5):

We ran into this problem in the office.  Our setup is with Asus motherboards, but I think everyone uses ASPEED BMCs, and they all use the same base JViewer software from AMI.  The symptom is we would get the same traceback as posted in the original question, but it would work fine under Linux and Windows.

Here's what we did. I'll admit this is one of the more strage ways to solve a problem... and it's total luck that we stumbled upon this as a solution (workaround, really.)  These are internal notes that several of use used to get it working.

- Remove X11.app on your Mac (drag to trashcan)
- Empty trashcan
- Install Java
- Then re-install X11.app ([XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/))

It appears you need X11 started to get it to work too. It will start automatically, but that seems iffy vs. starting it ahead of time.  If you don't reinstall X11.app, it doesn't work - it really needs to be there.

Comment: 3 years, later, installing XQuartz fixed my issue on Mojave, very helpful, had to have XQuartz running and Jviewer started working, +1

Comment: Works in macOS Monterey as well.